# Paginate Links not working

Tags: pages, pagination, users, wp-user-query, paginate-links

For the life of me I cannot get Paginate links to display pagination, but using 'userp' in the url works for paging. I just need the links to show up.

```
    <?php
/**
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage themename
 * Template Name: Vendors Page
 */

get_header(); ?>
<?php 
    $url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    $tokens = explode('/', $url);
    $usernameCheck = $tokens[sizeof($tokens)-2];
    if ($usernameCheck != 'vendors') {
        $username = $usernameCheck;
        $username = str_replace("-", " ", $username);
    }

    if(isset($_POST['gform_submit'])):
?>
    <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function(){
            jQuery('div.profileEdit').show();
        });
    </script>
<? endif; ?>
<?php 
    $currentUserID = get_current_user_id(); 
    $page = (!empty($_GET['userp'])) ? $_GET['userp'] : 1;
    $per_page = 10;
    $offset = ( ($page -1) * $per_page);
?> 
<div id="main">
        <div id="primary">
            <div id="content">

                <?php the_post(); ?>
                <div class="contentLeft">

                <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?> role="article">

                    <h1 class="entry-title"><?php if (!empty($username)) {echo $username; ?> <a class="profileEdit">Click Here To Edit Your Profile</a><?php }  else {the_title();} ?></h1>

                    <?php if (!empty($username)) { ?> 

                    <?php
                            // WP_User_Query arguments
                            $args = array (
                                'exclude'        => array( 1 ),
                                'count_total'    => true,
                                'fields'         => 'all_with_meta',
                                'meta_query'     => array(
                                    array(
                                        'key'       => 'user_business',
                                        'value'     => $username,
                                        'compare'   => 'LIKE',
                                    ),
                                ),

                            );

                            // The User Query
                            $user_query = new WP_User_Query( $args );

                            // The User Loop
                            if ( ! empty( $user_query->results ) ) {
                                foreach ( $user_query->results as $user ) { ?>
                            <?php if ( $currentUserID == $user->ID ) { ?><div class="profileEdit"><?php echo do_shortcode('[gravityform id="4" title="false" description="false"]'); ?></div><?php } ?> 
                            <div class="profileLeft">
                                <?php if (isset($user->user_pic)) { ?>
                                                <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/thumb.php?src=<?php echo $user->user_pic; ?>&w=235&h=147" title="<?php echo $user->user_business; ?>" alt="<?php echo $user->user_business; ?>" class="profilePic" />
                                <?php } else { $imgURL = get_template_directory_uri() . "/images/vendor_placeholder.jpg"; ?>
                                                <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/thumb.php?src=<?php echo $imgURL; ?>&w=235&h=147&zc=2" title="<?php echo $user->user_business; ?>" alt="<?php echo $user->user_business; ?>" class="profilePic" />
                                <?php } ?>
                                <h6>Owner Name:</h6>
                                <?php echo $user->first_name; ?>&nbsp;<?php echo $user->last_name; ?><br /><br />

                                <?php if ($user->user_address_show == 'Yes') { ?>
                                    <h6>Address:</h6>
                                    <?php echo $user->user_address_street; ?><br /><?php echo $user->user_address_city; ?>,&nbsp;KS&nbsp;<?php echo $user->user_address_zip; ?><br /><br />
                                <?php } ?>

                                <h6>Phone:</h6>
                                <?php echo $user->user_phone; ?>

                                <a href="mailto:<?php echo $user->user_email; ?>" class="contactVendor">Contact Us Via Email</a>

                                <h6>Markets We Attend:</h6>
                                <?php if (isset($user->we_attend_east)) { ?><div class="location east"><strong>East Wichita</strong><br />Green Acres Market</div><?php } ?>
                                <?php if (isset($user->we_attend_west)) { ?><div class="location west"><strong>West Wichita</strong><br />Sedgwick County Ext. Office</div><?php } ?>
                                <?php if (isset($user->we_attend_delano)) { ?><div class="location delano"><strong>Delano in Wichita</strong><br />Lawrence Dumont Parking lot</div><?php } ?>
                                <?php if (isset($user->we_attend_derby)) { ?><div class="location derby"><strong>Derby, Kansas</strong></div><?php } ?>

                                <?php if (isset($user->attend_this_week_east) || isset($user->attend_this_week_wast) || isset($user->attend_this_week_delano) || isset($user->attend_this_week_derby)) { ?>
                                <div class="attend">We will be at the 
                                <?php if (isset($user->attend_this_week_east)): ?>East Wichita Market<?php if (isset($user->attend_this_week_west) || isset($user->attend_this_week_delano) || isset($user->attend_this_week_derby)): ?>,<?php endif; ?><?php endif; ?>
                                <?php if (isset($user->attend_this_week_west)): ?>West Wichita Market<?php if (isset($user->attend_this_week_delano) || isset($user->attend_this_week_derby)): ?>,<?php endif; ?><?php endif; ?>
                                <?php if (isset($user->attend_this_week_delano)): ?>Delano in Wichita Market<?php if (isset($user->attend_this_week_derby)): ?><?php endif; ?><?php if (isset($user->attend_this_week_derby)): ?>&nbsp;and<?php endif; ?><?php endif; ?>
                                <?php if (isset($user->attend_this_week_derby)): ?>Derby, Kansas Market<?php endif; ?>
                                this week!
                                </div>
                                <?php } ?>

                                <h6>Items sold at market:</h6>
                                <ul class="profileItemsSold">
                                    <?php if (isset($user->product_1)){ ?><li><?php echo $user->product_1; ?></li><?php } ?>
                                    <?php if (isset($user->product_2)){ ?><li><?php echo $user->product_2; ?></li><?php } ?>
                                    <?php if (isset($user->product_3)){ ?><li><?php echo $user->product_3; ?></li><?php } ?>
                                    <?php if (isset($user->product_4)){ ?><li><?php echo $user->product_4; ?></li><?php } ?>
                                    <?php if (isset($user->product_5)){ ?><li><?php echo $user->product_5; ?></li><?php } ?>
                                </ul>

                                <?php if (isset($user->user_organic)){ ?>
                                    <div class="organic">Organic | Chemical Free</div>
                                <?php } ?>

                                <?php if (isset($user->user_producer)){ ?>
                                    <div class="producer">100% Producer</div>
                                <?php } ?>



                            </div>

                            <div class="profileRight">
                                <h6>About Us:</h6>
                                <p><?php echo $user->user_about; ?></p>
                            </div>

                            <div class="profileBottom">
                                <?php if (isset($user->user_profile_pic)){ ?><h1 class="entry-title">View Our Photos</h1><?php } ?>

                                <?php if (isset($user->user_profile_pic)){ ?>
                                    <div id="userPicsContainer">
                                        <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/user_pics_prev.png" class="prev"/>
                                        <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/user_pics_next.png" class="next"/>
                                        <div class="targetDiv">
                                            <ul>
                                                <li><a href="<?php echo $user->user_profile_pic; ?>" class="fresco" data-fresco-caption="<?php echo $user->user_profile_pic_c; ?>"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/thumb.php?src=<?php echo $user->user_profile_pic; ?>&h=134&w=119" alt="<?php echo $user->user_profile_pic_c; ?>" title="<?php echo $user->user_profile_pic_c; ?>" /></a></li>

                                                <?php if (isset($user->user_pic_1)){ ?><li><a href="<?php echo $user->user_pic_1; ?>" class="fresco" data-fresco-caption="<?php echo $user->user_pic_1_c; ?>"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/thumb.php?src=<?php echo $user->user_pic_1; ?>&h=134&w=119" alt="<?php echo $user->user_pic_1_c; ?>" title="<?php echo $user->user_pic_1_c; ?>" /></a></li><?php } ?>

                                                <?php if (isset($user->user_pic_2)){ ?><li><a href="<?php echo $user->user_pic_2; ?>" class="fresco" data-fresco-caption="<?php echo $user->user_pic_2_c; ?>"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/thumb.php?src=<?php echo $user->user_pic_2; ?>&h=134&w=119" alt="<?php echo $user->user_pic_2_c; ?>" title="<?php echo $user->user_pic_2_c; ?>" /></a></li><?php } ?>

                                                <?php if (isset($user->user_pic_3)){ ?><li><a href="<?php echo $user->user_pic_3; ?>" class="fresco" data-fresco-caption="<?php echo $user->user_pic_3_c; ?>"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/thumb.php?src=<?php echo $user->user_pic_3; ?>&h=134&w=119" alt="<?php echo $user->user_pic_3_c; ?>" title="<?php echo $user->user_pic_3_c; ?>" /></a></li><?php } ?>

                                                <?php if (isset($user->user_pic_4)){ ?><li><a href="<?php echo $user->user_pic_4; ?>" class="fresco" data-fresco-caption="<?php echo $user->user_pic_4_c; ?>"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/thumb.php?src=<?php echo $user->user_pic_4; ?>&h=134&w=119" alt="<?php echo $user->user_pic_4_c; ?>" title="<?php echo $user->user_pic_4_c; ?>" /></a></li><?php } ?>

                                                <?php if (isset($user->user_pic_5)){ ?><li><a href="<?php echo $user->user_pic_5; ?>" class="fresco" data-fresco-caption="<?php echo $user->user_pic_5_c; ?>"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/thumb.php?src=<?php echo $user->user_pic_5; ?>&h=134&w=119" alt="<?php echo $user->user_pic_5_c; ?>" title="<?php echo $user->user_pic_5_c; ?>" /></a></li><?php } ?>

                                                <?php if (isset($user->user_pic_6)){ ?><li><a href="<?php echo $user->user_pic_6; ?>" class="fresco" data-fresco-caption="<?php echo $user->user_pic_6_c; ?>"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/thumb.php?src=<?php echo $user->user_pic_6; ?>&h=134&w=119" alt="<?php echo $user->user_pic_6_c; ?>" title="<?php echo $user->user_pic_6_c; ?>" /></a></li><?php } ?>

                                                <?php if (isset($user->user_pic_7)){ ?><li><a href="<?php echo $user->user_pic_7; ?>" class="fresco" data-fresco-caption="<?php echo $user->user_pic_7_c; ?>"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/thumb.php?src=<?php echo $user->user_pic_7; ?>&h=134&w=119" alt="<?php echo $user->user_pic_7_c; ?>" title="<?php echo $user->user_pic_7_c; ?>" /></a></li><?php } ?>

                                                <?php if (isset($user->user_pic_8)){ ?><li><a href="<?php echo $user->user_pic_8; ?>" class="fresco" data-fresco-caption="<?php echo $user->user_pic_8_c; ?>"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/thumb.php?src=<?php echo $user->user_pic_8; ?>&h=134&w=119" alt="<?php echo $user->user_pic_8_c; ?>" title="<?php echo $user->user_pic_8_c; ?>" /></a></li><?php } ?>

                                                <?php if (isset($user->user_pic_9)){ ?><li><a href="<?php echo $user->user_pic_9; ?>" class="fresco" data-fresco-caption="<?php echo $user->user_pic_9_c; ?>"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/thumb.php?src=<?php echo $user->user_pic_9; ?>&h=134&w=119" alt="<?php echo $user->user_pic_9_c; ?>" title="<?php echo $user->user_pic_9_c; ?>" /></a></li><?php } ?>
                                            </ul>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                <?php } ?>

                                <?php if (isset($user->user_twitter) || isset($user->user_facebook)){ ?><h1 class="entry-title">Socialize With Us</h1><?php } ?>

                                <?php if (isset($user->user_twitter)){ ?>
                                    <div id="twitterUserContainer">
                                        <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/twitter_prev.png" class="prev"/>
                                        <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/twitter_next.png" class="next"/>
                                        <div class="targetDiv">
                                            <?php echo do_shortcode('[twitter-user]'); ?>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <br style="clear:both;" />
                                <?php } ?>

                                <?php if (isset($user->user_facebook)){ ?>
                                    <iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?href=<?php echo urlencode($user->user_facebook); ?>&amp;width=588&amp;height=590&amp;show_faces=true&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;stream=true&amp;show_border=true&amp;header=true&amp;appId=172839226207438" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:588px; height:590px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
                                <?php } ?>
                            </div>

                            <?php } } ?>

















                    <?php } else { ?>






                        <?php
                            // WP_User_Query arguments
                            $args = array (
                                'exclude'        => array( 1 ),
                                'count_total'    => true,
                                'fields'         => 'all_with_meta',
                                'number' => $per_page,
                                'offset' => $offset,
                            );


                            // The User Query
                            $user_query = new WP_User_Query( $args );

                            // The User Loop
                            if ( ! empty( $user_query->results ) ) {
                                foreach ( $user_query->results as $user ) { ?>

                                    <div class="vendorContainer">
                                        <a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/vendors/<?php echo str_replace(" ", "-", strtolower($user->user_business)); ?>">
                                            <?php if (isset($user->user_pic)) { ?>
                                                <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/thumb.php?src=<?php echo $user->user_pic; ?>&w=235&h=147" title="<?php echo $user->user_business; ?>" alt="<?php echo $user->user_business; ?>" />
                                            <?php } else { $imgURL = get_template_directory_uri() . "/images/vendor_placeholder.jpg"; ?>

                                                <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/thumb.php?src=<?php echo $imgURL; ?>&w=235&h=147&zc=2" title="<?php echo $user->user_business; ?>" alt="<?php echo $user->user_business; ?>" />
                                            <?php } ?></a>
                                            <div class="vendorContent">
                                                <h5><?php echo $user->user_business; ?><a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/vendors/<?php echo str_replace(" ", "-", strtolower($user->user_business)); ?>" class="viewProfile">View Profile</a></h5>
                                                <strong>Item(s) sold at market:</strong>
                                                <ul><?php $productCounter = 0; ?>
                                                    <?php if (isset($user->product_1) && $productCounter == 0) { $productCounter = 1; ?><li><?php echo $user->product_1; ?></li><?php } ?>
                                                    <?php if (isset($user->product_2) && $productCounter == 0) { $productCounter = 1; ?><li><?php echo $user->product_2; ?></li><?php } ?>
                                                    <?php if (isset($user->product_3) && $productCounter == 0) { $productCounter = 1; ?><li><?php echo $user->product_3; ?></li><?php } ?>
                                                    <?php if (isset($user->product_4) && $productCounter == 0) { $productCounter = 1; ?><li><?php echo $user->product_4; ?></li><?php } ?>
                                                    <?php if (isset($user->product_5) && $productCounter == 0) { $productCounter = 1; ?><li><?php echo $user->product_5; ?></li><?php } ?>
                                                </ul>
                                                <strong>Market(s) we attend:</strong><?php $marketCounter = 0; ?>
                                                <?php if (isset($user->we_attend_east) && $marketCounter != 2) { $marketCounter++ ?><div class="location east"><strong>East Wichita</strong><br />Green Acres Market</div><?php } ?>
                                                <?php if (isset($user->we_attend_west) && $marketCounter != 2) { $marketCounter++ ?><div class="location west"><strong>West Wichita</strong><br />Sedgwick County Ext. Office</div><?php } ?>
                                                <?php if (isset($user->we_attend_delano) && $marketCounter != 2) { $marketCounter++ ?><div class="location delano"><strong>Delano in Wichita</strong><br />Lawrence Dumont Parking lot</div><?php } ?>
                                                <?php if (isset($user->we_attend_derby) && $marketCounter != 2) { $marketCounter++ ?><div class="location derby"><strong>Derby, Kansas</strong></div><?php } ?>
                                            </div>
                                    </div>

                            <?php } } ?>







                    <?php } ?>

                <?php
                $page_args = array(
    'base'         => get_permalink( get_the_ID() ). '%_%',
    'format'       => add_query_arg(array('userp' => '%#%')),
    'total'        => ceil($users->total_users / $per_page),
    'current'      => $page,
    'show_all'     => True,
    'end_size'     => 2,
    'mid_size'     => 2,
    'prev_next'    => True,
    'prev_text'    => __('« Previous'),
    'next_text'    => __('Next »'),
    'type'         => 'plain',
);

echo paginate_links($page_args);
?>

                </article><!-- #post-<?php the_ID(); ?> -->
                </div>
                <?php if (!empty($username)) { ?><div class="contentRight"><?php if ( dynamic_sidebar('profile-sidebar') ) : else : ?><?php endif; ?></div><?php } else { ?><?php get_sidebar(); ?><?php } ?>
                </div>
            </div><!-- #content -->
        </div><!-- #primary -->
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: Your user query is `$user_query` but you are using `$users` in `paginate_links`. Pretty sure the problem is just a typo.

Comment: You were correct, totally overlooked it, thanks! Would you happen to know why the pagination doesn't show the change in current page? On any page, page 1 is still selected as current